# The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a big problem regarding the serialization of a Many to Many relationship with intermediate model in DRF: If the request method is get everything works perfectly. But as soon as i try to POST or PUT Data to the API I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/views.py", line 477, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/views.py", line 437, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/generics.py", line 243, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 26, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 888, in create
    raise_errors_on_nested_writes('create', self, validated_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.7.egg/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 780, in raise_errors_on_nested_writes
    class_name=serializer.__class__.__name__
AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `manager.serializers.EquipmentSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

I am not really sure how to write proper create and update functions and i don´t really understand it, how it is explained in the documentation.

Code:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from manager.serializers import *
from rest_framework import generics 
from rest_framework import viewsets 
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view 
from rest_framework.response import Response 
from rest_framework.views import APIView  
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict



class OrderSetDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView): 
    queryset = Order.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer 

class OrderSetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView): 
    queryset = Order.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer 

class EquipmentSetDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView): 
    queryset = Equipment.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = EquipmentSerializer 

class EquipmentSetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView): 
    queryset = Equipment.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = EquipmentSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer 

class ClientList(generics.ListCreateAPIView): 
    queryset = client.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers  
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from storage.models import * 


class AssignmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source = 'Order.id') 
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source = 'Order.name') 

    class Meta:
        model = Assignment 
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'quantity') 


class EquipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    event = AssignmentSerializer(source= 'assignment_set', many = True)
    class Meta: 
        model = Equipment 
        fields = '__all__' 


class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

    class Meta: 
        model = client 
        fields = '__all__' 

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name') 

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Order 
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models 
from storage.choices import *

# Create your models here.
class Equipment(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    fabricator = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='-') 
    storeplace = models.IntegerField() 
    labor = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=labor_choices) 
    event = models.ManyToManyField('Order', blank = True, through= 'Assignment', through_fields=('Equipment', 'Order')) 
    max_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, null = True) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default = 'im Lager') 





    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name 




class client(models.Model): 
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    secondname = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    email = models.EmailField() 
    post_code = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    street= models.CharField(max_length=30) 



    def __str__(self):              
        return "%s %s" % (self.firstname, self.secondname)



class Order(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    Type = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
        default='Rental', 
        )
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    street= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateField() 
    GuestNumber = models.IntegerField() 
    description = models.TextField() 
    client = models.ForeignKey("client", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null = True) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=order_choices, default='glyphicon glyphicon-remove') 

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name

class Assignment(models.Model): 
    Equipment = models.ForeignKey('Equipment',  on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    Order = models.ForeignKey('Order',  on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

DRF does not support `create` method for nested serializers. If you want to show related fields in an extended layout and not only with pks then you can override the `to_representation` method instead of rewriting default `mtm` field. You should also override a `create` method, because of the third model in `mtm` link:

```
class EquipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

    class Meta: 
        model = Equipment 
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=validated_data.pop('event'))
        instance = Equipment.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Assignment.objects.create(Order=order, Equipment=instance)
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(EquipmentSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['assigment'] = AssignmentSerializer(instance.assigment_set.all(), many=True).data
        return representation
```

Now it'll save mtm fields properly passing list of pks, like `[1, 2, 3]` and for representation of that mtm related model, `EquipmentSerializer` will use `AssignmentSerializer`.

Comment: This solves the AssertionError but now i get a 400 bad request detail: "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: @nictec ah I don't saw you used third model for mtm link

Comment: @nictec updated answer. Your code is not so clear it is really hard to debug from SO. If you'll have any error link it here and also update your answer with post request body

Comment: Some certifications are required in this answer:
in `create` function, change the following
`order = Order.objects.filter(pk__in=validated_data.pop('event'))`

also,
`for` loop will be required here since it is a `ManyToManyField`

Answer (score 7):

Maybe for most people who is having the same issue, this question is a quite long.

The short answer is that **DRF** does not support natively `create` method for nested serializers. **so what to do?**

Simply overriding the default behaviour. Check out a full example in the [Official DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but with the `update()` method ...

The solution was simple thanks to this thread: https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested/issues/104...

All I had to do was installing the library `pip install drf-writable-nested`
and import it:

`from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer`

the code should look like this:

(credit to: https://github.com/Leonardoperrella)

--serializers.py--

```
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('name', 'code', 'price')

class VendorsSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer,
                        serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductsSerializer(source='vendor', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Vendors
        fields = ('name', 'cnpj', 'city', 'products')
```

--models.py--

```
class Vendors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
    cnpj = models.CharField('CNPJ', max_length=14, unique=True, validators=[validate_cnpj])
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=100, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Vendor"
        verbose_name_plural = "Vendors"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=60)
    code = models.CharField('Code', max_length=13)
    price = models.DecimalField('Price',
                                max_digits=15,
                                decimal_places=2,
                                default=0.00,
                                validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal("0.01"))])
    vendor = models.ForeignKey('Vendors', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vendor')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Product"
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cause for error: `JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded` is because you forgot to put `.data` at the 2nd line from @Ivan Semochkin solution: `representation['assigment'] = AssignmentSerializer(instance.assigment_set.all(), many=True).data`.

Thus I find out that I will stumble upon `Keyword Error: 'event'` from line: `representation = super(EquipmentSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)` since the EquipmentSeralizer object contain the intermediary `assignment_set` instead of `event`.

Here are the end result adapting from @Ivan Semochkin solution I do. Correct me if I'm wrong/inappropriate in practice.

```
class EquipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

    class Meta: 
        model = Equipment 
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=validated_data.pop('assignment_set').get('id'))
        instance = Equipment.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Assignment.objects.create(Order=order, Equipment=Equipment)
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(EquipmentSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['assigment'] = AssignmentSerializer(instance.assigment_set.all(), many=True).data
        return representation
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm new to Django.