# django - making .create() support writable nested fields?

Tags: python, django

So in Django, .create() does not support writable nested fields. However, I have a nested field in my project. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394761/the-create-method-does-not-support-writable-nested-fields-by-default), which was helpful, but I'm now getting  a ValueError at /transactions/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Product001'. As far as I can tell, this is caused by the line in *serializer.py* that reads

```
product = Product.objects.get(pk=validated_data.pop('sku'))
```

specifically, the 'sku' value I have in there. My question is, what value should I put in there to replace 'sku'? The answer to the question I based my code on used 'event', but that's not part of my models in my project. I've also tried using 'product', and got a TypeError that sadi "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'collections.OrderedDict'".

*serializers.py*

```
from .models import Product, Family, Location, Transaction
from rest_framework import serializers

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = ('reference', 'title', 'description')

class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Family
    fields = ('reference', 'title', 'description', 'unit', 'minQuantity')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('sku', 'barcode', 'title', 'description', 'location', 'family')
    depth = 1

class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  product = ProductSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    fields = ('sku', 'barcode', 'product')

  def create(self, validated_data):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=validated_data.pop('sku'))
    instance = Transaction.objects.create(**validated_data)
    return instance

  def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(TransactionSerializer, self).to_representatio
n(instance)
    return representation;
```

*models.py*

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):

    sku = models.CharField(max_length=13,help_text="Enter Product Stock Keeping Unit")
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=13,help_text="Enter Product Barcode (ISBN, UPC ...)")

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter Product Title")
    description = models.TextField(help_text="Enter Product Description")

    unitCost = models.FloatField(help_text="Enter Product Unit Cost")
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10,help_text="Enter Product Unit ")

    quantity = models.FloatField(help_text="Enter Product Quantity")
    minQuantity = models.FloatField(help_text="Enter Product Min Quantity")

    family = models.ForeignKey('Family')
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular instance of Product.
        """
        return reverse('product-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title

class Family(models.Model):

    reference = models.CharField(max_length=13, help_text="Enter Family Reference")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter Family Title")
    description = models.TextField(help_text="Enter Family Description")

    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10,help_text="Enter Family Unit ")

    minQuantity = models.FloatField(help_text="Enter Family Min Quantity")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular instance of Family.
        """
        return reverse('family-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title

class Location(models.Model):

    reference = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Enter Location Reference")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter Location Title")
    description = models.TextField(help_text="Enter Location Description")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular instance of Location.
        """
        return reverse('family-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title

class Transaction(models.Model):

    sku = models.CharField(max_length=13,help_text="Enter Product Stock Keeping Unit")
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=13,help_text="Enter Product Barcode (ISBN, UPC ...)")

    comment = models.TextField(help_text="Enter Product Stock Keeping Unit")

    unitCost = models.FloatField(help_text="Enter Product Unit Cost")

    quantity = models.FloatField(help_text="Enter Product Quantity")

    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')

    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    REASONS = (
        ('ns', 'New Stock'),
        ('ur', 'Usable Return'),
        ('nr', 'Unusable Return'),
    )


    reason = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=REASONS, blank=True, default='ns', help_text='Reason for transaction')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular instance of Product.
        """
        return reverse('transaction-detail-view', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):

        return 'Transaction :  %d' % (self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find details about writable nested serialization [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Regarding your case you can get product's `sku` data from `product` dict:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
   product_data = validated_data.pop('product')
   try:
       product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_data.get('sku'))
   except Product.DoesNotExist:
       product = Product.objects.create(**product_data)

   instance = Transaction.objects.create(**validated_data)
   instance.product = product
   instance.save()
   return instance
```

Comment: just wanted point out how TERRIBLE DRF documentation was when you posted this comment, and how terrible still is today 6 years later. The "ManyToManyFields with a Through Model" is a 4 lines paragraph with not a single example. Deplorable