# Writable nested serializer with existing objects using Django Rest Framework 3.2.2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Consider a Listing model that has an associated Category. I want to create a new Listing for an existing Category by doing a POST with data: 
`{"title": "myapp", "category": {"name": "Business"}}`, where `title` is the title of the Listing that should be created, and `Business` is the name of an existing category to use for this new listing.

When I try to make such a request and instantiate the `ListingSerializer` for this, I get an error indicating that the Category name must be unique - I don't want to create a new Category, but use an existing one instead. I've tried setting the validators on the category field to `[]`, but that didn't change the behavior.

I can use a `SlugRelatedField`, but that forces my request data to look more like `{"title": "myapp", "category": "Business"}`, which isn't what I want. I tried using the `source` argument for the `SlugRelatedField` to specify a nested relationship, but that didn't work either:

```
category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='category.name',
        queryset=models.Category.objects.all()
    )
```

yields:

```
  "category": [
    "Object with name={'name': 'Business'} does not exist."
  ]
```

models.py:

```
import django.contrib.auth
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='listings', null=True)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(
        Profile,
        related_name='owned_listings',
        db_table='profile_listing',
        blank=True
    )
```

serializers.py:

```
import logging
import django.contrib.auth
from rest_framework import serializers
import myapp.models as models

logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')

class ShortUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = django.contrib.auth.models.User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = ShortUserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
        fields = ('user', 'display_name')
        read_only = ('display_name',)

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Category
        fields = ('name', 'description')
        read_only = ('description',)


class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owners = ProfileSerializer(required=False, many=True)
    # TODO: how to indicate that this should look for an existing category?
    category = CategorySerializer(required=False, validators=[])

    class Meta:
        model = models.Listing
        depth = 2

    def validate(self, data):
        logger.info('inside ListingSerializer validate')
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        logger.info('inside ListingSerializer.create')
        # not even getting this far...
```

views.py:

```
import logging

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

import django.contrib.auth

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

import myapp.serializers as serializers
import myapp.models as models


# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CategorySerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = django.contrib.auth.models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ShortUserSerializer

class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProfileSerializer

class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    logger.info('inside ListingSerializerViewSet')
    queryset = models.Listing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ListingSerializer
```

Full example: https://github.com/arw180/drf-example

Comment: Very thorough. I'm surprised this didn't get answered sooner.

Comment: https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested might be useful

Answer (score 5):

This isn't ideal, but I did find a solution that solved my problem (I'm waiting to accept it as the answer, hoping someone else can do better). There are two parts:

First, use the `partial=True` argument when initializing the `ListingSerializer` ( http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates). Then use the serializer's `validate` method to get the actual model instance corresponding to the input data.

Second, explicitly remove the validators for the `name` field in the `CategorySerializer`. This is especially lousy because it effects more than just the `ListingSerializer`.

Leaving out either piece will result in the validation errors being thrown at the time the serializer is instantiated.

modifications to views.py:

```
class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Listing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ListingSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = serializers.ListingSerializer(data=request.data,
            context={'request': request}, partial=True)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            logger.error('%s' % serializer.errors)
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                  status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

modifications to serializers.py:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Category
        fields = ('name', 'description')
        read_only = ('description',)
        # also need to explicitly remove validators for `name` field
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {
                'validators': []
            }
        }

class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owners = ProfileSerializer(required=False, many=True)
    category = CategorySerializer(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Listing
        depth = 2

    def validate(self, data):
        # manually get the Category instance from the input data
        data['category'] = models.Category.objects.get(name=data['category']['name'])
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        title = validated_data['title']

        listing = models.Listing(title=validated_data['title'],
            category=validated_data['category'])

        listing.save()

        if 'owners' in validated_data:
            logger.debug('owners: %s' % validated_data['owners'])
            for owner in validated_data['owners']:
                print ('adding owner: %s' % owner)
                listing.owners.add(owner)
        return listing
```

I'll wait a bit to accept this as the answer in case someone can come up with a better solution (like how to make the `source` argument work properly with a `SlugRelatedField`) - I have a working example using the solution above at https://github.com/arw180/drf-example if you want to experiment. I'd also love to hear comments regarding why the `extra_kwargs` stuff is necessary in the `CategorySerializer` - why isn't instantiating it like this: `category = CategorySerializer(required=False, validators=[])` sufficient (in the `ListingSerializer`)? UPDATE: I believe that doesn't work because the unique validator is added automatically from the DB constraints and run regardless of any explicit validators set here, as explained in this answer: http://iswwwup.com/t/3bf20dfabe1f/python-order-of-serializer-validation-in-django-rest-framework.html

Comment: You should accept this answer as it remains the "state of the art" (c.f. the [github issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2996)).  That ticket also has a link to a post by a core contributor that documents roughly the same.

Answer (score 4):

#### <strike>Turn `CategorySerializer.create` into an `update_or_create` method on `name`</strike>

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    # update_or_create on `name`
    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            self.instance = Category.objects.get(name=validated_data['name'])
            self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
            assert self.instance is not None, (
                '`update()` did not return an object instance.'
            )
            return self.instance
        except Category.DoesNotExist:
            return super(CategorySerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    ...
```

I recommend looking at the [`DRF` source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L792) when ever you need to create custom functionality.

Related question answered by the creator of `DRF`: [django-rest-framework 3.0 create or update in nested serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434593/django-rest-framework-3-0-create-or-update-in-nested-serializer)

#### Edit

So I was still in the DRF 2 mindset where nested writable fields are handled automatically. You can read up on the subject here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/

I've tested the following code and it works:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        ...
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {'validators': []},
            'description': {'required': False},
        }


class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    def update_or_create_category(self, validated_data):
        data = validated_data.pop('category', None)
        if not data:
            return None

        category, created = models.Category.objects.update_or_create(
            name=data.pop('name'), defaults=data)

        validated_data['category'] = category

    def create(self, validated_data):
        self.update_or_create_category(validated_data)
        return super(ListingSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        self.update_or_create_category(validated_data)
        return super(ListingSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

#### Edit

The correct way of using `SlugRelatedField` is like this, in case you were wondering:

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    # slug_field should be 'name', i.e. the name of the field on the related model
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name',
        queryset=models.Category.objects.all())

    ...
```

Comment: The validation errors come at the time the serializer is instantiated in the `ModelViewSet`, so even with these changes I still have the error.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it.

Comment: Although my use of `partial=True` is more concise, your solution will likely be better once I add support for the PUT request as well. It sill uses the `extra_kwargs` to remove the validators for the `CategorySerializer` class, which isn't ideal, though Tom Christie himself opted not to use the `ModelSerializer` in the answer you linked to, one benefit being it would avoid this problem with the auto-generated field validators. I'll probably accept this unless someone figures out a cleaner method using `SlugRelatedField`

Comment: If you try things such as leaving the field empty or undefined, you'll see that there is still validation being done.

Comment: Oh, you don't want this to create a new category if one doesn't exist with the requested name?

Comment: Correct - in my case, it is invalid to create a new Listing for a Category that does not already exist

Comment: regarding your `SlugRelatedField` example - my issue is when trying to use the slug field to reference a nested resource. For example, by setting the `slug_field` to `category.name`

Comment: What you're effectively getting by that is `category.category.name`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem: I needed to check if nested serializer (`CategorySerializer`)  exists if yes to use it and if not - create it from nesting serializer (`ListingSerializer`). The solution of @demux totally worked for me only if I didn't use custom validation for a field in nested serializer (the field by which I would check from nesting serializer if this instance exists). So I added `create()` method to nested serializer and  @demux custom `update_or_create_category()`, `create()`, `update()` for `ListingSerializer` worked perfectly.

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
    model = Category
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if Category.objects.filter(name=self.validated_data['name']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This category name already exists")
        return Category.objects.create(**validated_data)
```