# Displaying nested entities in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to display nested entities in the Django REST response – not hyperlinked entities or primary keys - the actual entity inside the parent.

This would look something like this:

```
{ 'id': 5
  'name' : 'blah'
  'children' : [
      {'id' : 77, 'foo' : 'bar'},
      {'id' : 78, 'foo' : 'bar'},
      ...
  ]
}
```

This is mentioned in the REST [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/)  as one possible way of representing relationships between entities, but the documentation doesn't indicate how it can be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-rest-framework 3.0 create or update in nested serializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434593/django-rest-framework-3-0-create-or-update-in-nested-serializer)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation indicates use of nested relationships:
[DRF Nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Basically you put the `related_name` of the child model in the serializer e.g. `related_name = ChildSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`. The link has a pretty good example.