# Django REST Framework: Flatten nested JSON to many objects

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I have this child model with parent field in it, and I'm getting a JSON from an API (which I can't control its format).

models.py:

```
class ChildModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    parent = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

API.json:

```
{
   "parent_name":'Homer',
   "children":[
      {
         "name":'Bart',
         "age":20
      },
      {
         "name":'Lisa',
         "age":15
      },
      {
         "name":'Maggie',
         "age":3
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to write a serializer that will get this JSON and will create 3 different child objects.

I manage to do this for one child:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    age = serializers.IntegerField()

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent_name = serializers.CharField()
    children = ChildSerializer(source='*')

    class Meta:
        model = ChildModel
        fields = ('parent_name', 'children')
```

But when there are more than one child for a parent, I don't know how to save multiple children.

I tried to change it like this:

```
children = ChildSerializer(source='*', many=True)
```

But the validated data looks like this:

```
OrderedDict([(u'parent_name', u'Homer'), (u'name', u'age')])
```

Any suggestions how to make it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434593/django-rest-framework-3-0-create-or-update-in-nested-serializer?rq=1

Comment: F.y.i. the plural of `child` is `children`. In some cases children might not need their own `Model`. drf supports [django's `ArrayField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.1-announcement/#new-field-types). Don't know if that helps.

Comment: @demux Thanks for the English lesson, I updated the post.
In my case I do need a child model (since I don't even have a parent model), so ArrayField is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to customize your serializer so that it creates all the children. For that, `create()` method is used.

Try this:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    parent_name = serializers.CharField()
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        parent_name = validated_data['parent']

        # Create or update each childe instance
        for child in validated_data['children']:
            child = Child(name=child['name'], age=child['age'], parent=valid, parent=parent_name)
            child.save()

        return child
```

The problem is that you don't have a `Parent` model. That's why I don't know what to return in the `create()` method. Depending on your case, change that `return child` line.

Hope it helps!